# Can store.dispatch method be called with string parameter in Angular 2 with NgRx store

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have received a test suit with few test cases and sample Angular 2 application with NgRx. I am not able to pass one test case and I am not sure if that test case is correct.

My question is does NgRx `store.dispatch` method accept string as parameter?

If not, then how this test case can be passed?

If yes, can you help me understand how to implement Action and reducer in this scenario?

Test case in trouble :

```js
it('should dispatch action when dispatchAction is called', async() => {
  // you need to spy on store's 'dispatch' method
  store = TestBed.get(Store);
  spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callThrough();

  // if you call function dispatchAction with 'movies' paramter. expect store to dispatch action='movies'
  component.dispatchAction('movies');
  fixture.detectChanges();

  expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('movies');
});
```

Component dispatch method:

```js
dispatchAction($event: string) {   
  // ToDo: need to write this.store.dispatch('movies') . But this method will not accept string parameter.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

The requirement is `[ 'movies' ]` but actual calls were `[ Object({ type: 'movies' }) ]`. That means the receiver part doesn't respect ngrx action interface. Therefore we need to break types here for the dispatch with `any` cast.

```js
dispatchAction($event: string) {   
  this.store.displatch($event as any);
}
```

if the test is fresh or you know his author I would recommend to discuss with him the solution, because the right way is to dispatch an object that respects Action interface, you can find it here, it has just a type property of string: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/667b5b3bf2a30429a5a85f61cfdcf10fa8ff3199/modules/store/src/models.ts#L1-L3

The assertion should looks like

```js
expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  jasmine.objectContaining({
    type: 'movies',
  }),
);
```

**ORIGINAL**

to dispatch a `movies` action simply use the `type` key of the action's interface:

```js
dispatchAction($event: string) {   
  this.store.displatch({type: $event});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering . I used the code you mentioned but test case failed with error NavbarComponent should dispatch action when dispatchAction is called FAILED
        Expected spy dispatch to have been called with [ 'movies' ] but actual calls were [ Object({ type: 'movies' }) ]. I guess my question is if dispatch accepts an action object,then how the test case can expect ['movies'].

Comment: I see, then I think the test checking the dispatch doesn't follow the ngrx pattern. Because the dispatch method requires an action: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/667b5b3bf2a30429a5a85f61cfdcf10fa8ff3199/modules/store/src/store.ts#L80. In your case then simply put cast to any `this.store.displatch($event as any);`, I've updated the answer too.